# Using sequelize and mysql, unable to update stuff

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am making an app that includes updating posts from the past. There is a separate page for this and a route to go with it.

```
  app.post("/posts/:id/update", function(req, res){
    Post.findAll({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }).then(function(foundPost){
        var updatePost = foundPost[0]
        updatePost.updateAttributes({
            description: req.params.description,
            author: req.params.author,
            image: req.params.image
        })
    });
    res.redirect("/posts")
 });
```

This code will find the post in the database, then attempt to update with the data received from the form on the update page. For some reason the post does not update at all, aside from the "updatedAt" date in the database. This is what comes out from the terminal after attempting to update a post:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `posts` SET `updatedAt`='2017-07-07 20:50:22' WHERE `id` = 4
```

It finds the correct post but does nothing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update method available at the model
Something like

```
Posts.update({
  image: req.body.image,
  title: req.body.title,
  // More properties to update
}, {where:{id:req.params.id}})
```

Comment: The code you posted seems to work, but I still come up with the same results.

Comment: var Post = connection.define("post", {
            description: Sequelize.TEXT,
            author: Sequelize.STRING,
            image: Sequelize.STRING
    });